# vkCreateSwapchainKHR fails with VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY

Tags: vulkan

I am attempting to create a swapchain after successfully creating an instance, surface, and device. However, vkCreateSwapchainKHR is failing with VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY.

What does this mean and what are the possible causes?

Device info:

- Device Name: GeForce GTX 970
- Driver Version: 1602764800
- Vulkan API Version: 4194346

API dump:
https://pastebin.com/pXebGX5t

EDIT: I think it may be related to pNext having a value here. It is set to NULL in my code so something deeper might be happening like a problem with my binding...

```
vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pDevice) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    physicalDevice:                 VkPhysicalDevice = 0000000004D768D0
    pCreateInfo:                    const VkDeviceCreateInfo* = 000000000022EAD0:
        sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO (3)
        pNext:                          const void* = 000000000022EB20
        flags:                          VkDeviceCreateFlags = 0
```

Comment: It means the device is out of memory. I'm not sure what more can be gleamed from that without your code. However, it could be due to exceeding `maxImageCount`, but we can't know that without looking at your code.

Comment: I have tried 1, 2, and 3 for minImageCount. My code is _very_ similar to https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/model_loading.cpp

EDIT: Wait, where do you set maxImageCount, dont you just query it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Hope I didn't deter you with Ada code :( I can post more to pastebin if you want to see

Comment: @RWilco8 It would be prefferable if you posted an `api_dump` so everyone can easily read this (and also to make sure there is no error in the bindings). Also: considering how many people somehow do not know this, just to be sure you should say if Validation Layers are enabled and found something or not.

Comment: @krOoze Validation Layers are not enabled and I am currently not using the SDK at all, but I will see what I can do and try to get an api_dump.

Comment: @RWilco8 Validation Layers SHOULD be enabled during development. Do you have a valid reason and understood and carefully weighted the full implications of having them disabled in the development phase?

Comment: @RWilco8 Doing `api_dump` only requires enabling the layer on `vkCreateInstance` (full name `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` — it needs the SDK installed too though) and then collecting the `stdout` (resp. `std::cout`) in console.

Comment: @krOoze I just really wanted to avoid installing a massive 12 Gb IDE and making more bindings to talk to Lunar... but I see that is not possible now given how opaque Vulkan is. Installing VS as we speak, yay ;/ EDIT: Ok seems easy enough, I am a bit concerned about collecting the output though. Wish me luck!

Comment: @krOoze Alright, posted the dump :)

Comment: @RWilco8 The LunarG SDK is ~600 MB. I don't see why you would need anything else that you are not already using. Validation Layers can even be enabled with an environment variable, even without the need to modify the source code.

Comment: @krOoze, yes this is great advice. I was assuming the SDK had to be compiled from their github sources. I found out my previous comment was misguided as I went through the process of installing the everything and getting the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the dump your swapchain requested format is a depth format (`VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT`).

That is highly suspicious.
Also something the validation layers probably check (there should be supported vs requested format check). So do yourself a favor and [enable them](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.49.0/windows/getting_started.html#user-content-enable-validation-layers).

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution to this problem that I came across, in case anyone else finds it useful. In my case, I was erronously trying to create a swapchain with the same HWND and HINSTANCE before destroying the previous one. The validation layer was mum about it and the error message (out of memory) isn't very useful. Hopefully I saved someone a decent amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also running into the VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY error even earlier, when enumerating the vulkan extensions (complete with subsequent warnings about missing ICD's etc..) :

After I checked every single compile and linker flag and replaced *all code* with the demo cube code that ran just fine, it appeared that an older vulkan-1.dll was still sitting next to the executable. The dll was probably not compatible with the linked .lib. Once that dll was deleted, the error disappeared!

It's typically a windows thing to run into just this kind of issues, so I hope this can help other people. Somehow it must have been copied in one of the CMake deployment installer runs.