# vkCreateGraphicsPipelines fails with VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT

Tags: vulkan

I have moved to a phase where I am attempting to create a pipeline with my Vulkan binding, but I am getting an "UNKNOWN" failure below.

Are any of my data structures malformed?

```
Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, pipelineCache, createInfoCount, pCreateInfos, pAllocator, pPipelines) returns VkResult UNKNOWN (-1000011001):
```

Entire API Dump - the call to vkCreateGraphicsPipelines happens at 1098:
https://pastebin.com/GVwZuKuz

I know in my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402036/vkcreateswapchainkhr-fails-with-vk-error-out-of-device-memory) that it was suggested I enable validation, but I have not yet been successful doing that (getting crashes attempting to enable validation) :/

Comment: Could have something to do with  VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/35
See also:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/commit/7e01ec07847290b54d6d8ad1e8a1d126ab419bb1

Comment: Your dump is cut at the start (use stream redirection instead like so `vkApp.exe > log.txt`).

Comment: To enable layers: 1) Install latest LnG SDK 2) go into console (cmd) and write `set VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` 3) From the same console run your app: `vkApp.exe > log.txt` 4) Your log.txt should contain all the error reports

Comment: That was the fix I needed - to run it directly from console instead of the IDE. @krOoze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From scanning over it at least the `sType` is wrong for `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo`.
You have `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO`.
Should be `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO`.

Comment: Good catch! After the fix the result is -1000012000

Comment: -1000012000  is VK_ERROR_INVALID_SHADER_NV, so if you directly pass glsl one of the shaders of that pipeline is probably invalid. As @krOoze said, you should start with enabling validation layers. Usually the nv driver will then also report why it has problems loading that shader. If that's not possible, upload you shaders somewhere so we can take a look at them.

Comment: @sascha I was at last able to get validation working following krOoze 's repeated advice. Because of this I have found multiple errors and am in the process of correcting them - I will post the shader code though if that indeed ends up being the culprit. Also, thank you guys so much : ). It is very difficult to be the first to use Vulkan in a new language with no bindings. I would not be able to do this with you.